# COBOL registry doesn't writing whole information

Tags: cobol

I'm learning COBOL and tried to do a little program that reads a file and then writes with format in another file but it doesn't writes whole information that is in the read file.

After writing WS-STATUS-EMP it stops writing in the output file.

.cbl code:

```
       IDENTIFICATION DIVISION.
       PROGRAM-ID.                PROG01.

       ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
       CONFIGURATION SECTION.

       INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
       FILE-CONTROL.
           SELECT EMPLEADOS ASSIGN TO "C:\COBOL\Archivos\EMPLEADOS.txt".
           SELECT REPORTE   ASSIGN TO "C:\COBOL\Archivos\REPORTE.txt".

       DATA DIVISION.
       FILE SECTION.
       FD EMPLEADOS
           LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD
           RECORD CONTAINS 50 CHARACTERS
           BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS
           DATA RECORD IS REG-EMPLEADOS.
       01  REG-EMPLEADOS          PIC X(50).

       FD REPORTE
           LABEL RECORDS ARE STANDARD
           RECORD CONTAINS 50 CHARACTERS
           BLOCK CONTAINS 0 RECORDS
           DATA RECORD IS REG-REPORTE.
       01  REG-REPORTE            PIC X(50).

       WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
       01  WS-AREAS-A-USAR.
           05 WS-REG-EMPLEADOS.
              10 WS-NUMERO-EMP    PIC 9(05).
              10 WS-NOMBRE-EMP    PIC X(30).
              10 WS-STATUS-EMP    PIC 9(01).
              10 WS-DEPTO-EMP     PIC 9(03).
              10 WS-PUESTO-EMP    PIC 9(02).
              10 WS-SALARIO-EMP   PIC 9(07)V99.
           05 WS-LEIDOS-EMP       PIC 9(05)    VALUE ZEROS.
           05 WS-IMPRESOS         PIC 9(05)    VALUE ZEROS.
           05 WS-TOTAL-SALARIOS   PIC 9(09)V99 VALUE ZEROS.

       01  WS-TITULO-1.
           05 FILLER              PIC X(27)    VALUE SPACES.
           05 WS-TIT-1            PIC X(25)
                                  VALUE "EMPLEADOS DE LA EMPRESA: ".
           05 FILLER              PIC X(28)    VALUE SPACES.

       01  WS-TITULO-2.
           05 FILLER              PIC X(01)    VALUE "/".

       01  WS-DETALLE.
           05 FILLER              PIC X(04)    VALUE SPACES.
           05 WS-DET-NUMERO       PIC ZZZZ9.
           05 FILLER              PIC X(04)    VALUE SPACES.
           05 WS-DET-NOMBRE       PIC X(30).
           05 FILLER              PIC X(04)    VALUE SPACES.
           05 WS-DET-STATUS       PIC 9(01).
           05 FILLER              PIC X(04)    VALUE SPACES.
           05 WS-DET-DEPTO        PIC 9(03).
           05 FILLER              PIC X(04)    VALUE SPACES.
           05 WS-DET-PUESTO       PIC 9(02).
           05 FILLER              PIC X(03)    VALUE SPACES.
           05 WS-DET-SALARIO      PIC Z,ZZZ,ZZ9.99.
           05 FILLER              PIC X(04)    VALUE SPACES.

       01  WS-DETALLE-LEIDOS.
           05 FILLER              PIC X(01).
           05 FILLER              PIC X(29)
                                  VALUE "TOTAL DE EMPLEADOS LEIDOS  : ".
           05 WS-TOT-LEIDOS       PIC 9(05).
           05 FILLER              PIC X(45)    VALUE SPACES.

       01  WS-DETALLE-IMPRESOS.
           05 FILLER              PIC X(01).
           05 FILLER              PIC X(29)
                                  VALUE "TOTAL DE EMPLEADOS IMPRESOS: ".
           05 WS-TOT-IMPRESOS     PIC 9(05).
           05 FILLER              PIC X(45)    VALUE SPACES.

       PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       010-INICIO.
           OPEN INPUT  EMPLEADOS
                OUTPUT REPORTE
           WRITE REG-REPORTE FROM WS-TITULO-1.
       020-LEE.
           READ EMPLEADOS INTO WS-REG-EMPLEADOS AT END
                GO TO 100-FIN.

           ADD 1 TO WS-TOT-LEIDOS
           MOVE WS-NUMERO-EMP     TO WS-DET-NUMERO
           MOVE WS-NOMBRE-EMP     TO WS-DET-NOMBRE
           MOVE WS-STATUS-EMP     TO WS-DET-STATUS
           MOVE WS-DEPTO-EMP      TO WS-DET-DEPTO
           MOVE WS-PUESTO-EMP     TO WS-DET-PUESTO
           MOVE WS-SALARIO-EMP    TO WS-DET-SALARIO
           WRITE REG-REPORTE FROM WS-DETALLE AFTER ADVANCING 1
           
           GO TO 020-LEE.
       100-FIN.
           WRITE REG-REPORTE FROM WS-DETALLE-LEIDOS AFTER ADVANCING 1
           CLOSE EMPLEADOS
                 REPORTE
           GOBACK.
```

Input file:

> 00100FERNANDOTOLEDO ESPEJEL        82003000320005000200JOSE MARIA MEDINA             51001000280006000300ROBERTO PEREZ GARCIA          80205000560007000400VENUSTIANO ESTRADA MENDEZ     76207000210000000500VALENTIN JIMENEZ OJEDA        810010001900080

Comment: Just a note: if you ever want to use COBOL (or any programming language) in production: **never trust unverified external data**.
Verify it (here after `READ`) and you have both control what happens (nice messsage before aborting or continuing, possibly skipping invalid records, ...)

Comment: As your input comes from a text file, the only thing that the COBOL runtime will ensure is that the file exists and (as you didn't  use `LINE SEQUENTIAL`) has a record of 50 bytes of "something". It could be all garbage, which would be especially bad for the numeric field. A class test like `IF NUMERIC` or checking other validity is quite cheap (compared to the actual disk io), so there's normally no good reason to NOT do that and then either abort or skip invalid records (commonly moving them to an error list).
A runtime _may_ abort for the `MOVE` to the edited fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`REG-REPORTE` is defined as `PIC X(50)` and therefore when you `WRITE REG-REPORTE FROM WS-DETALLE AFTER ADVANCING 1` you only write out the first 50 bytes of `WS-DETALLE`.

You probably want `REG-REPORTE` to be defined as `PIC X(80)`.

You also might want to think about restructuring your code to not use `GO TO`.  The following is untested, but you can see the idea.

```
   01  END-OF-INPUT-SWITCH PIC X VALUE 'N'.
       88  END-OF-INPUT VALUE 'Y'.

   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
   010-INICIO.
       OPEN INPUT  EMPLEADOS
            OUTPUT REPORTE
       WRITE REG-REPORTE FROM WS-TITULO-1.
       READ EMPLEADOS INTO WS-REG-EMPLEADOS AT END
            SET END-OF-INPUT TO TRUE
       END-READ
       PERFORM 020-LEE UNTIL END-OF-INPUT
       CLOSE EMPLEADOS
             REPORTE
       GOBACK.
   
   020-LEE.
       ADD 1 TO WS-TOT-LEIDOS
       MOVE WS-NUMERO-EMP     TO WS-DET-NUMERO
       MOVE WS-NOMBRE-EMP     TO WS-DET-NOMBRE
       MOVE WS-STATUS-EMP     TO WS-DET-STATUS
       MOVE WS-DEPTO-EMP      TO WS-DET-DEPTO
       MOVE WS-PUESTO-EMP     TO WS-DET-PUESTO
       MOVE WS-SALARIO-EMP    TO WS-DET-SALARIO
       WRITE REG-REPORTE FROM WS-DETALLE AFTER ADVANCING 1
       READ EMPLEADOS INTO WS-REG-EMPLEADOS AT END
            SET END-OF-INPUT TO TRUE
       END-READ
       .
```

Comment: Thanks cschneid, now problem solved! Why do you recomend to not use GO TO? I'm taking a course and the professor uses it.

Comment: @Jonas many people think GO TO is a bad idea and I just wanted to show how you can write this code without it.  I've used GO TO and think it's like most things, it can be good and it can be bad.

Comment: When taking a course...  you may also think about using `SECTION`s and "structured" `EXIT`s like `EXIT SECTION` and `EXIT PERFORM`, then you still have `GO TO` for jumping to a different paragraph but using `EVALUATE` you commonly don't _need_ to use `GO TO` any more,
Not using `GO TO` has the benefit that you can easily use tools that show code-flow, those often have issues with "non-structured" programming.